# Python Webkit autoscroll

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I've added a `WebKit.WebView()` to a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow()`

I want the webview to constantly load a local HTML file using:

`WebView.load_html_string(html, base)`

The web pages grows longer and longer and every time it is refreshed the scrolled window scrolls back to the top. I want to stop this but am having difficulty.

I have tried adjusting the `vadjustment` of the scrolled window every time the webview is refreshed but this doesn't work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
previous = scrolled_window.get_vadjustment().value #Value before refresh
update_webview() #This method loads the new HTML file
scrolled_window.get_vadjustment().value = previous
```

But it doesn't work. The scroller seems to scroll where I want it to but then it moves straight back to the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set the corresponding adjustment but the HTML needs some time to render so **after** it finishes loading the adjustment value is reseted.

I once solved this problem by connecting to the changed signal of the vadjustment.
The problem with this signal is that it also gets emitted when the user scrolls. So if you set the value every time the signal is emitted, the user is unable to scroll. Therefore, you have to make a condition that checks if you changed the view and want the adjustment to be set.

```
class webviewscroll:
    def __init__(self):
        #webview = ...
        #scrolled_window = ...
        self.vadjustment = scrolled_window.get_vadjustment()
        self.vadjustment.connect('changed', self.on_vadjustment_changed)
        self.scroll_position = {'html_changed': False, 'value': 0}

    def update(self):
        self.scroll_position['html_changed'] = True
        self.scroll_position['value'] = self.vadjustment.get_value()
        self.update_webview() #This method loads the new HTML file

    def on_vadjustment_changed(self, adjustment):
        if self.scroll_position['html_changed'] == True:
            self.vadjustment.set_value(self.scroll_position['value'])
            self.scroll_position['html_changed'] = False
```

Comment: **Thanks**. That's the solution I came to as well.